# Convert Long to Raw jdbc

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have the following function defined:

```
private RAW[] longToRaw(long[] toConvert) throws SQLException  
{  
     final RAW[] toReturn = new RAW(toConvert.length);  
     for(int i = 0; i <toReturn.length;i++)
     {
          toReturn[i] = new RAW(toConvert[i]);
     }  
}
```

A client passes me `long[]` and this will not change.  The Oracle database I talk to stores data as `RAW`.  The data appears to be correctly persisted.  However, upon retrieval I get unintelligible results.

Retrieval code:

```
...
while(results.next())  
{    
     String s = new String(results.getBytes(1));
}    
...
```

This does not give the desired long value that was passed into the database.  How can I resolve this issue?  That is to say is the issue in the way I convert `long` to `RAW` or is it in my retrieval code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're calling a deprecated constructor, which additionally is meant for `byte` arrays and `String`s only. I believe the appropriate way would be like this:

```
toReturn[i] = RAW.newRAW(Long.toHexString(toConvert[i]));
```

EDIT: If `results` is an `Iterator<RAW>`, the `while`-loop should be changed to this:

```
while(results.hasNext()) {
    String s = new String(results.next().getBytes());
}
```

If `results` is a `RAW`-array, you should do it like this:

```
for(RAW result : results) {
    String s = new String(result.getBytes());
}
```

Comment: @Woot4Moo I did not look closely enough at your retrieval code, sorry. I deleted my previous comment.